# Button Class interacting with various-types of objects

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance, sfml

Using SFML, I created a simple button class that I plan to develop into a more advanced GUI that will do things in a game I making. Right now I'm trying to decide how buttons interact with other objects in the game. I need these buttons to be able to interact with game objects, other buttons, really a lot of things that aren't even created yet. The solution I came up with was this:

```
template <typename T> class Button 
{T* myLink;};//you can imagine functions that do things to the object at this address
```

This way the button has a link to what it plans to interact with, and I figured using templates was good because now I can tell the button what type it's going to be activating/changing. Next I wanted to make a Menu class that would just be a box that held a bunch of buttons. But this Menu class can't just have a single vector of Buttons because each Button is a different class depending on what type it was created with.

What's the best solution to this problem, should the Menu class be a template that can hold multiple types of Buttons, or should I be using inheritance somehow? If inheritence, please make a short example.

Thank You.

Comment: Can a `Button` do anything other than send `buttonUp` and `buttonDown` signals to the thing (or things) it's connected to?

Comment: No, that is all it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using Boost Signals would be a good solution.  That way, your menu can hold a vector of buttons since they won't be depending on a type.

```
class Button
{
public:
    boost::signal<void ()> pushed; 
}
```

You can have a different signal for whatever "interactions" you need your button for.

Comment: Thanks, I have never used Boost, or Signals, before, but I will figure it out. Can I use this software in something I plan to sell?

Comment: Yes boost has its own license which "encourages both commercial and non-commercial use."  http://www.boost.org/users/license.html